# AutoMapper.Map ignore all Null value properties from source object

Tags: c#, .net, repository, automapper

I'm trying to map 2 objects of the same type.
What I want to do is AutoMapper to igonore all the properties, that have `Null` value in the source object, and keep the existing value in the destination object.

I've tried using this in my "Repository", but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TEntity, TEntity>().ForAllMembers(p => p.Condition(c => !c.IsSourceValueNull));
```

What might be the problem ?

Comment: Hi, can we configure the condition for all classes? I tried `Mapper.CreateMap<TEntity, TEntity>` but it doesn't work (The type or namespace name 'TEntity' could not be found). Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip null values with custom resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021633/skip-null-values-with-custom-resolver)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Interesting, but your original attempt should be the way to go. Below test is green:

```
using AutoMapper;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Tests.UI
{
    [TestFixture]
    class AutomapperTests
    {

      public class Person
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public int? Foo { get; set; }
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestNullIgnore()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Person>()
                    .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));

            var sourcePerson = new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Bill",
                LastName = "Gates",
                Foo = null
            };
            var destinationPerson = new Person
            {
                FirstName = "",
                LastName = "",
                Foo = 1
            };
            Mapper.Map(sourcePerson, destinationPerson);

            Assert.That(destinationPerson,Is.Not.Null);
            Assert.That(destinationPerson.Foo,Is.EqualTo(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can we configure the condition for all classes? I tried `Mapper.CreateMap<TEntity, TEntity>` but it doesn't work (The type or namespace name 'TEntity' could not be found). Thanks.

Comment: For later versions, the answer be @nenad is the right way. You can also check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43947731/2929906

Answer (score 15):

`Condition` overload with 3 parameters let's you make expression equivalent to your example `p.Condition(c => !c.IsSourceValueNull)`:

Method signature:

```
void Condition(Func<TSource, TDestination, TMember, bool> condition
```

Equivalent expression:

```
CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>.ForAllMembers(
    opt => opt.Condition((src, dest, sourceMember) => sourceMember != null));
```

Answer (score 1):

So far I've solved it like this.

```
foreach (var propertyName in entity.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p=>!p.PropertyType.IsGenericType).Select(p=>p.Name))
   {
      var value = entity.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(entity, null);
      if (value != null)
      oldEntry.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(oldEntry, value, null);
    }
```

but still hoping to find a solution using AutoMapper

Answer (score 0):

Taking Marty's solution (which works) one step further, here is a generic method to make it easier to use:

```
public static U MapValidValues<U, T>(T source, U destination)
{
    // Go through all fields of source, if a value is not null, overwrite value on destination field.
    foreach (var propertyName in source.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => !p.PropertyType.IsGenericType).Select(p => p.Name))
    {
        var value = source.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(source, null);
        if (value != null && (value.GetType() != typeof(DateTime) || (value.GetType() == typeof(DateTime) && (DateTime)value != DateTime.MinValue)))
        {
            destination.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(destination, value, null);
        }
    }

    return destination;
}
```

Usage:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public int? Age { get; set; } 
    public string Role { get; set; } 
}

Person person = new Person() { Name = "John", Age = 21, Role = "Employee" };
Person updatePerson = new Person() { Role = "Manager" };

person = MapValidValues(updatePerson, person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Work Around - Add DataMember property in destination type **[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]** will remove the property if the source value is null.

```
[DataContract]
class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    [DataMember]
    public int? Age { get; set; } 

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Role { get; set; } 
}
```

if the Role value is null Role property will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it's worked

```
.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
```