# Automapper skip null values for all classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20025835/3387187) we can set Automapper to skip null value from source object.
Can we configure the condition for all classes automatically?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can configure *anything* for all classes automatically in Automapper, you'll have to write the code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.ForAllMaps((typeMap, map) =>
                    map.ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Condition((src, dest, srcMem, destMem) => src != null)));
}
```

I used `ForAllOtherMembers` so that it does not override your other conditions that you may declare individually.