# How to configure Automapper to ignore Object-Properties if properties is null but map if not null

Tags: c#, lambda, automapper

I am using Automapper. In that, I mapped the DTO objects with another object.

UserProperties Class.

```
public string DisplayName { get; set; }

public int Id { get; set; }

public int NotesCount {get;set;}
```

PersonsDTO class

```
public string UserName { get; set; }

public int UserId { get; set; }

public int NotesCount { get ; set; }

public int BooksCount { get; set; }
```

Persons class

```
public UserProperties? UserDetails { get; set; }

public int NotesCount { get ; set; }

public int BooksCount { get; set; }
```

In Mapping Profile,

```
CreateMap<PersonsDTO, Persons>()
             .ForPath(o => o.UserDetails.DisplayName, b => b.MapFrom(z => z.UserName))
             .ForPath(o => o.UserDetails.Id, b => b.MapFrom(z => z.UserId))
             .ReverseMap();
```

In my case, `UserDetails` in the `Persons` class is a nullable type. If `UserId` in the `PeronsDTO` class is `0` means, I no need to map UserDetails. It should returns as null for the UserDetails property.

How can I achieve it?

Automapper Version: 9.0.0

Comment: Is there any solution on this?

Comment: are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677087 - or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621702 - or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947475

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a custom resolver to explicitly do your custom mapping.

```
    CreateMap<PersonDTO, Person>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.UserDetails, opt => opt.MapFrom<CustomResolver>());

    public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<PersonDTO, Person, UserProperties>
    {
        public UserProperties Resolve(PersonDTO source, Person destination, UserProperties member, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            if (source.UserId == 0)
                return null;
            return new UserProperties
            {
                DisplayName = source.UserName,
                Id = source.UserId
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes tried by adding the condition like this...But it does not working.

Comment: Can you tell me the behavior you're seeing from both my suggestions if they don't work? The conditional statements should prevent the mapping from taking place if the condition isn't met

Comment: The above conditional statements should prevent the mapping for the inner properties only like UserDetails.DisplayName. I need to prevent tha mapping for the UserDetails class itself.

Comment: I changed the answer to use a custom resolver instead.