# Avoiding flattening of property "Value" in AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

We are working with AutoMapper 4.1.1 (will soon update to 6, but we need some time to change the project) and have this issue: in the source class we have a property "int? MyProp" while in the destination we have string "MyPropValue", which should not be mapped from MyProp. AutoMapper however does map it when the value of MyProp is not null (using MyProp.Value, flattened). We could use Ignore() to ignore the mapping but as we have dozens of such properties, we are looking for a way to do it with one configuration, without breaking the rest of the mapping.

Here is some example code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var map = Mapper.CreateMap<Dto, Model>();
        var dto = new Dto() {MyProp = 10};
        var model = Mapper.Map<Dto, Model>(dto);
        Console.WriteLine(model.MyPropValue);   // MyPropValue should be empty but it gets mapped
    }
}

public class Dto
{
    public int? MyProp { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public string MyPropValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: We will go with renaming all our properties to be called MyPropSomethingElse instead of MyPropValue, but it would be interesting to see if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
  .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));
```

Allows you to skip all nulls.
[Automapper skip null values with custom resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021633/automapper-skip-null-values-with-custom-resolver)

Comment: I don't have a problem with null values, just the opposite - with non-null values.

Comment: I believe your solution would involve using Conditions tweaked to your liking.