# How to ignore mapping source null values globally?

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there a way to ignore mapping null values to destination **globally** (for all mapping configurations)?

Something that goes in here:

```
    //Automapper config
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        //Initializes all mapping profiles in the assembly
        cfg.AddProfiles(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);

        //If map is called without a profile creates default map
        cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
    });
```

This is for instance mapping. Here is one example of what i'm trying to accomplish.

```
//Models
    class User {
      public string Name {get; set;}
      public string Email {get; set;}
      public string Password {get; set;}
    }

    class UserDto {
      public string Name {get; set;}
      public string Email {get; set;}
    }

//Start instances
     var user = new User { Name = "John", Email = "john@live.com", Password = "123"};

     var userDto = new UserDto { Name = "Tim" };
//Notice that we left the Email null on the DTO


//Mapping
    Mapper.Map(userDto, user);
```

The result ends up with the user having a null email. I want the user email to not be changed unless a new email is provided on the source (userDto). In other words **ignore all null properties of all types** on the source object from overwriting destination (User)

**UPDATE:** None of the answers below solve the problem. They simply do not work for collections. While the Autommaper figures out this bug I was able to get around my problem by using an ExpandoObject to filter out all null properties before mapping as below:

```
var patchInput = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;

foreach (var property in userDto.GetType().GetProperties())
    if (property.GetValue(userDto) is var propertyValue && propertyValue != null)
        patchInput.Add(property.Name, propertyValue);

Mapper.Map(patchInput, user);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automapper skip null values with custom resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021633/automapper-skip-null-values-with-custom-resolver)

Comment: Can you please add an example?

Comment: @Valerii Added the part where the config should go above. not sure if thats what you wanted.

Comment: @DonO Thanks. Can you also explain phrase "ignore mapping null values to destination". What behavior do you expect?

Comment: @Valerii just updated again hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: @DonO Thanks. Now I understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It should work

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfiles(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
            cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
            cfg.ForAllMaps((typeMap, map) =>
                map.ForAllMembers(option => option.Condition((source, destination, sourceMember) => sourceMember != null)));
        });
```

Comment: This answers my question but it seems that the other conditions defined on individual mapping profiles no longer work. :\

Comment: @DonO It works for Nulable numbers like int?, for value types like int it won't work because value cannot be null.

Comment: @DonO For collections it is a defect in AutoMapper. For collections you can use my alternative solution. cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable, IEnumerable>().ConvertUsing(new IgnoringNullValuesTypeConverter<IEnumerable>());

Comment: @DonO Why unaccepted? It works for example you provided.

Comment: @Valerri  CreateMap<IEnumerable, IEnumerable>().ConvertUsing(new IgnoringNullValuesTypeConverter<IEnumerable>()); wont work because it needs to be IEnumerable<T> but the problem is the types of collections aren't the same.

Comment: @DonO. IEnumerable<T> is inherited from IEnumerable. I tried List<int> -> List<int>, List<int> -> ObservableCollection<int>, ObservableCollection<int> -> ObservableCollection<int>. It works.

Comment: What about something like IList<User> to IList<UserDto> . Its a valid map given there is a profile for the objects these lists contain however now you have two different types. How would you handle that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155547/discussion-between-dono-and-valerii).