# Error on mapping an entity on another with a property more using Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to mapping a entity in another with similar properties but I would like to have a field more in my "destination type".
I want to map a Entity that use the destination value for a null field of the source class and I don´t want to have all fields mapped on my source type.

Have a look at the example:

```
[TestClass]
public class Example
{
  public class Person
  {
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public int? Foo { get; set; }
  }

  public class DPerson
  {
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public int? Foo { get; set; }
      public bool IsUser { get; set; }
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void TestNullIgnore()
  {
      Mapper.CreateMap<Person, DPerson>()
          .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));

      var sourcePerson = new Person
      {
          FirstName = "Bill",
          LastName = "Gates",
      };
      var destinationPerson = new DPerson
      {
          FirstName = "",
          LastName = "",
          Foo = 1,
          IsUser = true
      };
      Mapper.Map(sourcePerson, destinationPerson);

      Assert.IsNotNull(destinationPerson);
      Assert.AreEqual(1, destinationPerson.Foo);
      Assert.AreEqual(true, destinationPerson.IsUser);
  }
}
```

When I added IsUser property at DPerson class The AutoMapper throws an odd exception "AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException" and in its message it said that it is not possible to map "Person -> Boolean".

If I remove ".ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull))" configuration it works but I got "null" at the Foo property.

I adpated the code of the first answer for this question: [AutoMapper.Map ignore all Null value properties from source object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514084/automapper-map-ignore-all-null-value-properties-from-source-object)

Can anyone help me?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is odd--but it *does* make sense that `IsSourceValueNull` is not working in this particular case. Since `IsUser` is of type bool, its value can never be `null`.

This means that when AutoMapper evaluates `IsSourceValueNull` for that property, it's getting "false" every time for the `IsUser` property. Then, it tries to map the `IsUser` property and fails.

One way to fix this is to explicitly ignore the `IsUser` property:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, DPerson>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IsUser, opt => opt.Ignore())         
    .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));
```

Comment: I said it was odd because the message that was written in the exception sounds to me likes the API was trying to map my class into a bool value that is because I thought it was odd, by the way when I specified the conditional ".ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));" I Supposed that I was setting up the fields from my source class "IsSourceValueNull" and my source class (Person), all the fields are nullable. I am still thinking it should have worked. Anyway it is my first project using AutoMapper and I am just supposing.

Comment: Can you do this to check types instead? Say you're trying to get double but once in a while you get string. And you want to skip over that or set to 0.0